# Android - Pull down to refresh the whole page

Tags: android, android-layout, pull-to-refresh

I am making a feature that will let users to pull down a page anywhere in the application to check if they have a connection to the database server. I have followed this website, but it needs to Scrollview or ListView to function. All of my layouts are in a RelativeLayout only. Is there a way to do this without converting my whole layout to a ScrollView?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.infomaninc.appinlisv2.NewClaim">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/rlHeader" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#1BB52D"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/rlFooter" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/footer_value"
        android:id="@+id/tvFooter"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/tvLoggedOn"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't mind the contents of the code. It's just a snippet of a page.
How will I implement the pull down to refresh if my page looks like this?

So far I have followed this tutorial:https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-Pull-to-Refresh-Guide#step-2-setup-swiperefreshlayout

Answer (score 7):

You can also look for `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Although it needs a `ScrollView/ListView` as a child, but it wouldn't matter since all your data is being displayed in a single page. Just remember to set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `ScrollView` and you'll do fine. You can go ahead as follows:

```
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_id_for_swiperefreshlayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        //reload the data
    }
```

Comment: I actually did this but it just screwed up my app. It consumed too much frames for who knows what the reason is. My app kept crashing after I did this. Sad.

Comment: It's quite understandable. May I have a look at the logcat output for the same?

Answer (score 3):

I not sure if use `RelativeLayout` is your mandatory requirement, but you can put all your `RelativeLayout` in `ScrollView`. Then add `OnScrollListener` to refresh.

```
<ScrollView>   

    <RelativeLayout> 
           // all your relativelayout
    </RelativeLayout> 

 </ScrollView>
```

in the Java code

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onScrollChanged() {
    //example
    View view = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));
    if(diff == 0 || scrollView.getScrollY() == 0 ){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Refresh",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Example given detect `ScrollView` reached bottom when scroll down or top when scroll up. Can use scrollview and child properties to create refresh logic.

Comment: Will the onScrollChanged run only if you pull down from the top? or it will run so long as you scroll it?

Comment: Is there anything you can add to share how to do the refresh logic, detect that you're scrolling off the top?

Comment: @OrdinaryProgrammer  It will run when you scroll up or down.

Comment: @o0rebelious0o Scrollview will give information about top, bottom, width and height. From there you can add your refresh logic. I will update my answer later with refresh logic.